# X and Y intercepts

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I have a function:

> $$y =\begin{cases}
>          3x, &\text{if } x ≠ 0; \\
>          4, & \text{if } x = 0.
>         \end{cases}$$

As I understand, function doesn't exist at (0;0).
So, what are the intercepts?

Comment: What do you mean $(0,0)$ ?.  The point on the function at $x = 0$ is $y = 4$, i.e. $(0,4)$.

Comment: @Shailesh I mean that at point (0; 0) isn't continuous. Anyway, what are the intercepts here?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Where does it contact the $ \ y-$ axis? Its graph does not meet the $ \ x-$ axis.

Comment: The X-Intercept is given by putting $y = 0$ and the Y-Intercept by putting $x=0$. The intercepts means where does the graph touch the axes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(0)=4$, then this is by definition the y-intercept.

For the x-intercept, you must solve for the case $f(x)=0$. Clearly, this is not the case for $x=0$, since $f(0)=4$. Then check $f(x)=3x=0$. This is only true for $x=0$. Thus, there is no x-intercept, it does not exist. For a line, it only intersects with the x-axis (At most) once. In the case of $b=0$, for  $y=mx+b$, this is always at the origin of the graph. However, that doesn't work for this particular function, since it is defined differently at $x=0$.